# Displaying an object in angular2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, couchdb

OK, I have this

```
{ "calledCust": { "no": 270, "yes": 9 }, "hasOpened": { "no": 254, "yes": 25 } }
```

and I have been trying this to display in the view.

```
<ul *ngFor="let profile of profiles.counts">
  <li>
    {{profile | json}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

because it is not a json array, angular just blows up with

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

and I really want to display the results as below.

- calledCust  YES:9
- hasOpened YES:25

Many thanks

EDIT

here is the full json

```
{
    total_rows: 279,
    bookmark: "g2wAAAABaANkAB5kYmNvcmVAZGI0LnBvcnRlci5jbG91ZGFudC5uZXRsAAAAAmEAYj____9qaAJGQAnZi4AAAABiAAAB7mo",
    rows: [],
    counts: {
        calledCust: {
            no: 270,
            yes: 9
        },
        hasOpened: {
            no: 254,
            yes: 25
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whare is `counts` prop inside object?

Comment: @PankajParkar I have edited the question, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert it to a JSON array, something like:

```
let key; // var key for old JavaScript ES5
let arr = [];

key = 'calledCust';
arr[0] = obj[key];
arr[0].key = key;

key = 'hasOpened';
arr[1] = obj[key];
arr[1].key = key;
```

would be easy to create a pipe that will take your object and covert it to a JSON array then you would just do:

```
<ul *ngFor="let profile of profiles.counts | convertObjToJsonArray">
```

You can iterate over the properties of an object to make this solution more generic.